# Javascript, async, send custom var

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm using the following code http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/ to make async calls but now I want to send custom var to this script and cannot figure it out.

```
(function() {
function async_load(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'http://yourdomain.com/script.js';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent('onload', async_load);
else
    window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false);
})();
```

Now I want to have custom var that is sent to "script.js". That's all, a simple var to be sent to JS. I've even tried by using query strings but no results.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it to the global scope (with `window.varname = value` for example) and the script you load will be able to use it, since it runs on the same page.

Comment: Thank you! "window." is the one thing I did not try! Works.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean send to script ? Loaded script can access page and all global variables. Just declare global variable and your script can access in regular way.